# What's the correct texture for masa dough?

Tags: dough, tortilla, masa

Recently I bought a big thing of masa harina and tried making pupusas and tortillas. I forget which recipe I used, but I remember it saying to get the dough to a "playdoh" like texture. The dough was soft but did not stick to my hands. The problem is that when I cooked it on a pan, it didn't seem to cook through before the outside got really dry. I used medium-low heat and a bit of oil. The recipe said 2-3 minutes per side, but it was still raw at that point.

I did some research and found that kneading it helps the water get absorbed into the flour better, and that it dries out quicker than wheat flour. However, kneading it didn't seem to help, and I did cover it while it rested with a wet paper towel.

Any tips?

Comment: How thick did you press them, and how much oil? Mine are usually totally cooked in about 2 minutes total, and you need hardly any oil. Your pan should be quite hot though.

Comment: @SourDoh I pressed them to about 1/4 in  or less, and it was a very small amount

Comment: They should be closer to 1/16 inch. They need to be quite thin.

Comment: Backing up SourDoh's comment. They need to be very thin. I never oil my cast iron flat griddle when making torillas or rotis (chapatis) but I guess it's what a person gets used to. To get the correct temperature of your pan takes a bit of adjusting at first till you know the correct setting on your stove. Cast iron is best as it holds the heat well and you won't get temperature fluctuations.

Comment: @Jude I see... so it's really more about how thin I press them, and the temperature of the pan rather than trying to get my dough wetter. thanks!